# Call function in parent's parent from inside jquery's .each

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, each

I've created a 'class' in javascript called QuoteProductService(), see below.
I've added two functions to the prototype and now, I'm trying to call one of the functions (getQuoteProductFromArray) from within a jquery $.each inside the other function (getFakeQuoteProducts). This doesn't work. I've tried adding 'this.', but this also does not work, because 'this' inside the .each refers to the current element in the loop.

How should I do this ?

```
function QuoteProductService() {

}

QuoteProductService.prototype.getQuoteProductFromArray =  function(quoteproductarray, quoteproductid){
     var founditem=null;
     // do stuff
    return founditem;
}

QuoteProductService.prototype.getFakeQuoteProducts = function(){
    // do something to fill the mappedQuoteProducts array
    $.each(mappedQuoteProducts, function (index, quoteproduct) {
        if (quoteproduct!=-null) {
            if (quoteproduct.parentid != "") {
                // this is where it goes wrong :
                var parent = getQuoteProductFromArray(mappedQuoteProducts, quoteproduct.parentid);
                if (parent != null) {
                    parent.attachChild(quoteproduct);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Save a reference to your `QuoteProductService` instance before calling `each`

```
QuoteProductService.prototype.getFakeQuoteProducts = function(){
  var _this = this;
  // do something to fill the mappedQuoteProducts array
  $.each(mappedQuoteProducts, function (index, quoteproduct) {
      if (quoteproduct!=-null) {
          if (quoteproduct.parentid != "") {
              // this is where it goes wrong :
              var parent = _this.getQuoteProductFromFlatArray(mappedQuoteProducts, quoteproduct.parentid);
              if (parent != null) {
                  parent.attachChild(quoteproduct);
              }
          }
       }
    });
}
```

Comment: It's also common to name this variable `that` or `self`.

Comment: `self` is a reserved word (afaik) and used to reference the `window` object by the browser. [more information at mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.self). Beside that, it's a matter of taste I think. I personally don't like `that`.

Answer (score 1):

Add `var self = this;` to the beginning of the `getFakeQuoteProducts` function. Then call `getQuoteProductFromFlatArray` like this: `self.getQuoteProductFromFlatArray`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you provided wrong method name - `getQuoteProductFromFlatArray` instead of `getQuoteProductFromArray`. Secondly in JS you must provide scope for instance methods. 
Easiest way to achieve this is to store `this` reference into some other, private variable. See the example below.

```
function QuoteProductService() {

}

QuoteProductService.prototype.getQuoteProductFromArray =  function(quoteproductarray, quoteproductid){
     var founditem=null;
     // do stuff
    return founditem;
}

QuoteProductService.prototype.getFakeQuoteProducts = function(){
    var me = this; // store this into me

    // do something to fill the mappedQuoteProducts array
    $.each(mappedQuoteProducts, function (index, quoteproduct) {
        // this === me will return false
        if (quoteproduct!=-null) {
            if (quoteproduct.parentid != "") {
                // this is where it goes wrong :
                var parent = me.getQuoteProductFromArray(mappedQuoteProducts, quoteproduct.parentid);
                if (parent != null) {
                    parent.attachChild(quoteproduct);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```